# ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python

I use this statement twice in my program. The second time it fails.

```
output=""
pitcherName=input("Enter name of the next contestant, or nothing to quit: ")
pitcherTime=input("Enter time for " +str(pitcherName)+ " in milliseconds: ")
highestSpeed=pitcherTime
lowestSpeed=pitcherTime
fastestPitcher=pitcherName
slowestPitcher=pitcherName
while pitcherName!="":
    pitcherName=input("Enter name of the next contestant, or nothing to quit: ")
    pitcherTime=float(input("Enter time for " +str(pitcherName) +" in milliseconds: "))
    pitcherSpeed=round(40908/pitcherTime, 2)
    output=output +str(pitcherName)+ "\t" +str(round(pitcherTime, 2)) + "\t"  +str(round(pitcherSpeed, 2)) + "\n"
    if fastestPitcher==pitcherName and pitcherSpeed>highestSpeed:
        fastestPitcher=pitcherName
        highestSpeed=pitcherSpeed
    elif slowestPitcher==pitcherName and pitcherSpeed>lowestSpeed:
        slowestPitcher=pitcherName
        lowestSpeed=pitcherSpeed
print("Name" + "\t" +"Time" +"\t" +"Speed" + "\n" + "===========================" + "\n")
print(output)
print("Slowest pitcher was " +str(slowestPitcher) +" at " +str(round(lowestSpeed, 2)) +" miles per hour")
print("Fastest pitcher was " +str(fastestPitcher) +" at " +str(round(highestSpeed, 2)) +" miles per hour")
exit=input("Press nothing to`enter code here` exit")
```

Error received:

```
pitcherTime=float(input("Enter time for " +str(pitcherName) +" in milliseconds: "))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I know this may be a basic question, but I'd like to know why it worked outside of the `while` loop, but not inside of it. Is it not required to convert to float after is has been done already?

Comment: It won't work if the input from the user is not convertible to a `float`. It depends on what the user types in.

Comment: Can we have some more context?

Comment: What you give as the input? Remember that you can give only one float in one line.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this didn't work almost certainly has nothing to do with your `while` loop. In the absence of unincluded code that's doing something really strange, the reason it's most probably failing is that the input provided by the user cannot be converted to `float`. (For example, if they typed `1.0fzjfk` in your `input`, in which case with `float()` you're actually calling `float("1.0fzjfk")`, which is impossible.)

The substance of your problem is almost entirely predicated on user input, though, so it's difficult to point out exactly where and how it failed on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way, try and cath the exception raise ValueError

```
while pitcherName!="":
    try:
        pitcherName=input("Enter name of the next contestant, or nothing to quit: ")
        pitcherTime=float(input("Enter time for " +str(pitcherName) +" in milliseconds: "))
    except ValueError:
        print "input error"
```

its taken in consideration pitcherName has some value before while

Answer (score 0):

This will occur when the user types in a value that is inconvertible to a float.  You can detect if this occurs by wrapping it in a `try...except` like this:

```
try:
    pitcherTime=float(input("Enter time for " +str(pitcherName) +" in milliseconds: "))
except ValueError:
    continue # Start the loop over if they enter an invalid value.
```

Really though, merely putting this inside a while loop isn't going to change the error.  Not entirely sure what you meant by that, considering you didn't give much context.

Answer (score 0):

Ty this approach

```
def get_time():
    pitcherName = input("Enter name of the next contestant, or nothing to quit: ")
    goodinput = False
    while not goodinput:
        try:
            pitcherTime = float(input("Enter time for " + str(pitcherName) + " in milliseconds: "))
            goodinput = True
        except ValueError:
            goodinput = False
            print("Invalid Input")



get_time()
```

Answer (score 0):

Previously you said

> I use this statement twice in my program. The second time it fails.
>
> ```
> pitcherTime=float(input("Enter time for " +str(pitcherName) +" in milliseconds: "))
> ```

If you didn't changed the code, that was not true.

```
# case 1
pitcherTime=input("Enter time for " +str(pitcherName)+ " in milliseconds: ")

#later...

#case 2
pitcherTime=float(input("Enter time for " +str(pitcherName) +" in milliseconds: "))
```

There is a difference.

`input` read one line from `stdin` and returns it as string. The result (string) you store in `pitcherTime` in first case.

In second case, you write a prompt, get string, and then **try to convert it to `float`**.
At the moment the error occurs. Python says **exactly** what went wrong:

```
could not convert string to float:
```

[As furkle said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26703061/3821804), it simply means that you gave string which can't be converted to `float`.

So, the problem is not in your code. The problem is in input you or anyone gives to the program.